# Adding multiple items in a single list view row

Tags: android, listview

I have list view which can have[image] multiple items per row (same type but different values). Each List View item has left and right arrows with it. But I am unable to get that how to add multiple values per row, and how to switch them later.

Here is my **get view:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beer_list_item, parent,false);
        holder.tv_brandTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_BrandName);
        holder.tv_packSizeOption = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_packSizeOption);
        holder.img_manufacturerLogo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_brandBigLogo);
        holder.img_canBeerLogo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_canBeerImg);
        holder.tv_CanOrBottle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_CanOrBottle);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_brandTitle.setText(findBeerDataList.get(position).getBrandName());

    int numOfProducts = findBeerDataList.get(position).getBeerProductList().size(); 
    holder.tv_CanOrBottle.setText(findBeerDataList.get(position).getBeerProductList().get(0).getCanOrBottle());

    if(findBeerDataList.get(position).getBeerProductList().get(0).getCanOrBottle().equalsIgnoreCase("can")){
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(findBeerDataList.get(position).getCanImage(), holder.img_canBeerLogo);
    }
    else{
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(findBeerDataList.get(position).getBottleImage(), holder.img_canBeerLogo);

    }

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(findBeerDataList.get(position).getBrandLogo(), holder.img_manufacturerLogo);
    holder.tv_packSizeOption.setText(findBeerDataList.get(position).getBeerProductList().get(0).getPackOption()+"×"+findBeerDataList.get(position).getBeerProductList().get(0).getPackSize()+"ml");

    return convertView; 
}
```

**Here numofproducts is the size of the views in LIst ROW.**

**Please suggest me a good means to do the same**

Comment: So you want to have more items next to each other?

Comment: @GeraltYes, they should move with the help of arrows, as I have shown in the list view row, shown above

Comment: @GeraltAnd there can be any number of items present in the list view. They are not fixed, I want them to add at the runtime

Answer (score 0):

Just make one combined view wrapped in i.e. `RelativeLayout` and hide some views with `View.GONE`. Once arrow is pressed you unveil next view and hide the previous.

Comment: @Marcon there can be any number of items present in the list view. They are not fixed, I want them to add at the runtime

Comment: You can do so as you can modify row's view w/o any problems. So adding  or removing items is not a problem.

Comment: But how to update it for single row, as arrows in all the rows are diiferent. Can you provide me any example\

Comment: Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

On click of Right arrow, replace the content of the current view with new one i.e. the Next Item and on click of Left arrow replace it with the previous one.

Comment: very nice, replacing the content is the main issue i am experiencing. I have to do it all in the list view adapter'

Comment: see my structure of code and the list view getView method, and then replu

Comment: ?? Where are you now ?